# How to execute callable statement without no output parameters using JdbcDaoSupport

Tags: java, spring

My code is this :

```
public void deleteOption(final int quoteId, final int optionId) {
        this.getJdbcTemplate().execute(new CallableStatementCreator() {
            @Override
            public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
                CallableStatement cs = (CallableStatement) con.prepareCall(
                        " BEGIN "+
                        "   NTNQUOTE.QUOTE_TAB.DELETE_QUOTE_OPTION(   ?,?  ); "+
                        " END;");

                cs.setInt(1, quoteId);
                cs.setInt(2, optionId);
                return cs;
            }
        }, new CallableStatementCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public String doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement cs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                cs.execute();
                return "SUCCESS";
            }
        });
    }
```

Here there is no output by executing this callable statement but anyway i have to unnecessarily return a string or something,
Is there any alternative way to do this

Comment: Try using `CallableStatementCallback<Void>` instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: error : insert dimensions to complete refernce type

Comment: Are you using `Void` with a capital "V"?  That's an object type.  `void` with a lowercase "V" is a primitive type and cannot be used with generics.

Comment: so what i have to return for the function ' new CallableStatementCallback<Void>() {}' both return void and Void is not working

Comment: @EricGalluzzo `CallableStatementCallback<Void>` is no use, you will still need to return something because `Void` is a reference type and it's not `void`.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Agreed, but you can return `null`, and using `Void` instead of `String` makes the intent more clear.

Comment: ok is there any way to do without  CallableStatementCallback